# What will be the logic of the answer?

Tags: logic, pattern-matching

I have this reasoning question (image)
[image]

So, what I did is I found the number of dots in this, which came out to be:
2  5    11
7  13  19
5   ?   17
And I can't really find what's the pattern in this.
What I could see is :
5+6=11
13+6=19
x+6=17 so, x = 11

But what will be with 2,7 and 5 then?
Please explain me :)

Comment: Do you know what prime numbers are?

Comment: @MJD Yes, those with only two factors, 1 and the number itself. Like 1,3,5,7,11 etc..

Comment: You left out an important example! 2 is also prime.

Comment: @MJD  Damn!!! All the dots in the numbers are prime numbers (including 2, sorry I forgot to mention that)!! And the option 2 is the only one which has prime numbers (it's 11) . Rest are composite!!!! -_-